# Возможна ли инициализация имен data, computed из полученных данных от сервера?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть следующий код:

```js
    export default{
    
       data () {
        return {
          sender: '',
        }
      },
    
      components:{
        InputTextApp,
      },
    
      computed: {
    
        sender_additionData: {
          get () {
            return this.sender;
          },
          set (value) {
            this.sender = value;
          }
        },
    
     },
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Вопрос:

Существует ли гипотетическая возможность - генерировать инициализацию переменных:

1. Data
2. Computed
3. Возможно каких то других сущностей `vue.js`

По принципу, если я получаю обьект(перед построением дом дерева) от апи сервера - следующего вида:

```
{data:[sender], components:[InputTextApp], computed:[sender_additionData]}<br />
```

то происходила бы распаковка этого обьекта
и инициализация его данными соотвествующих структур Vue файла?